# Image processing library

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv

I recently downloaded OpenCv library and i am trying to use its functionality but unfortunately i am unable to do so.This is the class that i have written

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Opencv;

import hypermedia.video.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 

 */
public class LoadImage
{
    public LoadImage()
    {


        OpenCV opencv = new OpenCV( );
        opencv.loadImage( "one.png", 200, 100);
        image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );
      //  image( opencv.loadImage("one.png.jpg"), 0, 0);


    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
               LoadImage im=new LoadImage();
    }
}
```

I am using netbeans IDE and it shows no syntatic error.However after running this  i get the following error.

```
!!! required library not found : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\OpenCV.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
Verify that the java.library.path property is correctly set and the '\path\to\OpenCV\bin' exists in your system PATH

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: hypermedia.video.OpenCV.loadImage(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    at hypermedia.video.OpenCV.loadImage(Native Method)
    at Opencv.LoadImage.<init>(LoadImage.java:20)
    at Opencv.LoadImage.main(LoadImage.java:30)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

however i have done everything as in i have imported the library,have placed the OpenCv.dll files practically everywhere.But i keep on getting this error.Help

Comment: First, which Opencv package/version have you downloaded? Versions compiled for desktop windows are a C++ or Python library, not Java. You seem to have downloaded some non-official Java port (it doesn't even look like JavaCV).

Comment: I downloaded it from http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/download/01/opencv_01.zip Thank you for the suggestion:).

Comment: That is an ancient OpenCV version from circa 2008! Please visit OpenCV site (http://opencv.org/) or this Java version (http://code.google.com/p/javacv/).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that java can not find proper DLL -  openCV is invoked via JNI.  Here is useful answer:
[OpenCV to JNI how to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441198/opencv-to-jni-how-to-make-it-work)

Comment: Unless you want him to build jni wrappers for "all" opencv functions, that is not very helpful.

Comment: if he likes to have opencv in java he has to get wrappers and dlls somewhere ( or build them from scratch if there are none )

Comment: Thank you everyone .I will check  JNI out .Thank you:) p.s. i am a girl:)

Comment: Some guy made a java wrapper to opencv, it will probably be added soon to opencv library :)